# Only allow UIPageViewController to scroll when not touching inside UIImageView

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiimageview, uipageviewcontroller

In XCode/Swift, Is it possible to have a UIPageViewController that will only scroll horizontally when the touch happens outside of a UIImageView that is contained within the page controller's pages?

So far from searching similar questions, I can only find a way to disable all touch inside the UIPageViewController, but doing that makes the UIImageView untouchable. The code below shows how I'm imagining this could work if at all possible...

```
@IBOutlet weak var MyImageView: UIImageView!
var location = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)

override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    var touch : UITouch! = touches.anyObject() as UITouch
    location = touch.locationInView(self.view)

    if /* 1.) detect if touch is inside of MyImageView */ {
        // 2.) Disable Page Controller scroll but still
        // allow any kind of touch actions to take place within MyImageView
    } else {
        // 3.) Enable Page Controller scroll?
    }
}
```

1.) I could easily come up with a primitive way of handling this. But figure I could learn something from somebody more experienced with Swift

2.) Cannot figure this out...

3.) Cannot figure this out...

Again I'm new to this... Let me know if there's more information I need to provide, and thanks for taking a look at this problem!

Answer (score 1):

1) You need to check if the view contains the point of the hit.

```
view.frame.contains(point)
```

2) What you can do is log the current content offset of the scrollview, and each frame keep setting the content offset to the same value (this lets you enable touch interactions but keeps the content at the same place:

```
scrollview.contentOffset = frozenContentOffsetValue
```

3) Just stop assigning the above contentoffset when you want to allow scrolling again.

**//Updated based on using a UIPageView controller instead of a UIScrollView**

1) Same as above, check if `view.frame.contains(point)`

2) If your view does contain the point what you do is this:

```
UIPageViewController.view.userinteractionEnabled = false
UIPageViewController.view.userinteractionEnabled = true
```

What that does is disable the effects of the current touch but will allow touches again the next time. But its set up so it always cancels the touch when its from your UIView you want to cancel touches from.

Comment: This looks good, but ".contentOffset" seems like it's only a property of UIScrollView... Right now my heirarchy goes like this: UIPageViewController > UIViewController > UIImageView. Am I doing that wrong if I want the content to be scrolled through like pages rather than one continuous scroll?

Comment: Your question is not clear sorry. From what you described this will work, I don't understand what your asking?

Comment: Sorry... What I'm trying to say is that [UIPageViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/index.html) does not have the [.contentOffset](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/contentOffset) property. So your answer doesn't apply to my question unless you're saying I can get this to work using a UIScrollView instead.

Comment: So use a UIScrollView instead of a UIPageViewController

Comment: Right... Ok I appreciate your help, but it's not that simple, because like I said I need this to scroll in a page like manner (which is the whole point the UIPageViewController exists). Anyways thanks. I'll post an answer if I figure this out.

Comment: Thanks, Aggressor! By the way your answer to "1.)" is exactly the syntax I needed to know. Your updated answer for "2.)" doesn't appear to work though unfortunately. However I've gotten a bit further on that part of the logic... But the saga continues with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28868818/changing-uipageviewcontrollers-datasource-causes-touch-delay-only-with-the-sc) post. I still plan to have the accepted answer posted here when I've solved all the issues.